# Magento 2 reviews and details show together

Tags: magento2, product, product-review

In my product page I have the details and reviews shown separated but I want them in the same part. I have this:

[image]

where "Detalhes" is the details part and "Avaliações" is the review part. I want it to look like this:

[image]

Could someone tell me how can I do that? I´m kind of lost

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright if we want to do this we'll first have to look at how these elements are constructed in the original layout/phtml files.

1. If you check **module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml** you'll see an element `<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">` that seems to be the wrapper for the `product.info.description` element as well as an additional `product.attributes` element.
2. Similarly, in **module-review\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml** you can see a block called `reviews.tab` being added to the `product.info.details` block

So to change this behavior we can make a simple adjustment by overriding **Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml** in our theme:

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml**

```
<div class="product-info-wrap">
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

Clear the cache and you'll no longer see the tab structure. You can now make adjustments to the individual blocks and templates to match your desired design.